# docker compose erroring out about python files when starting React apps

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

  _helpers:
    container_name: _helpers
    image: node:14
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run start"]
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./_helpers:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  _root_config:
    container_name: _root-config
    image: node:14
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run start"]
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./_root_config:/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3000

  login_panel:
    container_name: login_panel
    image: node:14
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run start"]
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./loginpanel:/app
    ports:
      - 3002:3000

  navbar:
    container_name: navbar
    image: node:14
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run start"]
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./navbar:/app
    ports:
      - 3003:3000

  navigation:
    container_name: navigation
    image: node:14
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run start"]
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./navigation:/app
    ports:
      - 3004:3000
```

And here are the directories I have in the folder:

```
$ ls
docker-compose.yml  _helpers  loginpanel  navbar  navigation  react-components  _root-config
```

Right now, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[5823] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

When trying to run `docker-compose up`. What am I missing?

The projects start when I manually run `npm run start` in each directory.

Comment: That error message suggests Docker isn't running.  The `docker-compose.yml` file you're showing isn't really using any Docker features, though, just running `node` on your host code; could you use Node without Docker here?

Comment: The whole point of this is to use docker-compose for development purposes in a microservice architecture. With this setup I can start, stop, restart services as needed. Can I do this with node alone?

Answer (score -1):

I was missing permissions. Fixed with this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

```
sudo groupadd docker

sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

newgrp docker
```

then tested with

```
docker run hello-world
```